How to Identify the File Causing Cypress Webpack Compilation Error: 'Unexpected character �'
I've recently migrated a react-scripts web-app from React 17 to 18. The app functions correctly, including the Cypress component tests, but the Cypress E2E tests fail with a Webpack compilation error. Everything worked fine before the migration, and I am unsure how to identify the source of the issue.
Error Message:
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

What I want to achieve:

I need to locate the file or resource causing this error. The error message doesn't provide the file path, which makes it hard to debug.

Desired Error Message (with file path):
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) in file './path/file.extension'


What I’ve Tried:

Searched extensively online for solutions but couldn't find a fix.
Compared this app with a very similar web-app (same dependencies, shared files and test setup), which doesn’t throw this error.
Attempted to reproduce the issue in a fresh app, but the error does not occur there.
Ran tests with DEBUG=cypress:* npm run cypress-e2e, but it didn’t provide any additional useful information.
Reviewed all imports, removed or disabled some suspicious imports, and still encountered the error.
Removed dependencies not found in the other working app—no change.
Checked all 137 files modified during the migration to ensure no binaries were added that could cause this issue.

Question: How can I get Cypress or Webpack to reveal the path of the file that’s causing this error? Without the file path, it's difficult to debug or determine which binary or unsupported file is being parsed incorrectly.
Additional Context:

Both apps use react-scripts and have similar setups, but only this one throws the error.
Redoing the migration is not feasible due to the significant time investment and the need to migrate to a new UI library for React 18 compatibility.

Any advice on how to track down the file causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Update/FYI:
I found the issue and described it in a comment in @Azog's answer, as the question was closed by the community. In case it's re-opened, I'll post full details about how I did find it, etc.

Your details are sketchy but if you created a working "reproducer app" why are you not using it?

As I wrote above - I have two complex apps which are similar - one works one doesn't. So to reproduce I probably have to add most of the not working app to the reproducer app, unsure if I can actually reproduce it (it does not reproduce the error yet). Thus my specific question: Is there any way to get the path of the file causing the trouble from cypress? I have seen other error Cypress Webpack Compilation error messages with a path, so it must be possible somehow. This would also help all others, seeing this unspecific error message in the future.

Please don't vote "close this question" without leaving a comment how I should improve the question. Unfortunately, I cannot see the reasons for "closing the question". I'll add the reproducer as soon as I can actually reproduce it, but it will take me 1-3 weeks I guess. My hope was that there is something in Cypress which allows me to get more details than "any of your thousand files cannot be loaded". I've already temporarily removed all imports of images and am not importing a font. I have no idea how to trace this further down without brute-force re-writing the whole app.

You mean the reproducer? Yeah I can do this, but this will take weeks. I cannot transfer the source to the other, working app, as it's a different app. My question was if there is a way to make Cypress (or Webpack) output the file causing the issue, instead of re-writing/porting an entire app. The question is not about "how to fix this app" but does somebody know if/how to make Cypress output the path of the file causing the issue. Because sometimes it does just that (see other topics on this issue).

Looks like the upgrade failed at some point, restore and try again. I don't understand how 3 or 4 copy/pastes can it take weeks?

To upgrade to React 18 I have to switch different dependencies which do not support React 18 etc. I guess it's impossible to get the path of the causing file. We might just switch to another test framework for E2E then, we don't have that many E2E tests so that's actually less work.

I actually found the cause of the issue. Unfortunately, I cannot post the answer as the question is closed. I tried to rephrase the question, could you undo the closing please? The answer will contain the reproducer (it does not make so much sense in the question).

My guess is you copy/pasted a text with a different encoding in a new file, setting the encoding of that said file to a different one than you usually have.
My suggestion is to go through all your files to see what's the encoding of every file in your project and see the one which differs from the others.
I tested on LMDE 6 the different methods described in this website : https://www.baeldung.com/linux/detect-text-encoding-automatically
But the only method that worked for me with the differently_encoded.txt file is the one with a python script using the lib chardet.
Here is what I did :
Installed the lib :
sudo apt install python3.12-venv
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate  # Activate the virtual environment
pip install chardet        # Install the package inside the virtual environment

Adapted the script to go through subdirectories, and saved that file to detect_encoding.py
import chardet
import os

def detect_encoding(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            chunk = f.read(1024)
            result = chardet.detect(chunk)
            encoding = result['encoding']
            return f'Encoding={encoding}' if encoding else 'Encoding not detected'
    except Exception as e:
        return f'Error: {e}'

# Ask the user for a directory to search
directory_to_search = input("Please enter the directory to search: ")

exclude_directories = set(['build', '.git','node_modules'])    #directory (only names) you want to exclude
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_search):  # Search in the user-specified directory
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_directories] # exclude directory if in exclude list 
    for fname in files:
       fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)   #this generate full directory path for file
       # Only show files with non-ASCII encodings and exclude ASCII files explicitly
       if encoding and encoding.lower() not in ['encoding=ascii', 'encoding not detected']:
           print(fpath, ':', detect_encoding(fpath))

Launched the script :
python detect_encoding.py
Or
python3 detect_encoding.py

And it gave a result like this:
./deploy.sh : Encoding=ascii
./test.py : Encoding=ascii
./.bash_aliases : Encoding=ascii
./.bashrc : Encoding=ascii
./differently_encoded.txt : Encoding=ISO-8859-1
./.inputrc : Encoding=ascii
./README.md : Encoding=utf-8

The guilty file will most certainly show up.
After that, just convert the file to utf-8 (probably) with an editor and see which character(s) is/are guilty.
Replace these chars with "good" ones and you're done.

Thanks for the reply. I accepted it as bounty reward. Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the issue - I renamed and unlinked all files which are not ascii encoding, but this did not fix it. Weird.

I actually found the file causing the issue - it was one of the direct imports in my test file. It did not show ob on the "non ascii" files output. As soon as I know more. I'll port an answer here. Still, thanks for the reply @Azog

Good news. Thanks for the bounty @hbo..Glad to read you're unstuck. I'm really curious about the root cause also.

I cannot post an answer as this question was closed by the community, I'm sharing the actual issue here, until the question is reopened: In my Cypress E2E test file I imported a utils.js which imported another file, which imported another file :). That file imports .png files which lead to the "cannot load binary file" error. Seems easy to find, but I thought I have to search all transitive imports of all 137 changed files, not only the transitive imports of the E2E test file. You are still my hero @Azog ;-)

Thanks a lot for your feedback ! That's nice to read :). I will be proud to come back to your solution if me or one of my colleagues gets stuck the same way ;). Thanks.
